# fortran initializing a derived type inline or type casting

Tags: casting, fortran, type-conversion, gfortran, derived-class

I want to know if there is a way to pass a derived type inline in a subroutine. Suppose that I have a module

```
 module test_mod

 type a
 end type

 type b
 end type

 contains

 subroutine test(var)
 type(a),intent(in) :: var
 ...
 end subroutine

 subroutine test(var)
 type(b),intent(in) :: var
 ...
 end subroutine

 end module
```

Where I could implement this module with something like

```
 program testTest
 use test_mod
 call test(type(a)::temp)
 ! call test(type(a)::temp) ! or
 end program
```

I know this can be done in c++ using something like (double)(i), but this is a conversion. I'm interested in (I guess) initializing a derived type inline

Comment: What did your compiler say when you fed that source to it ?

Comment: I get a "Syntax error in argument list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using is alien to the language, but you can use *structure constructors*.

It is a function which returns the type and it has the same name as the type. Every derived type has a default one and you can define your own by overriding the type name in a generic interface. The arguments of the default constructor are the type components.

```
program testTest
 use test_mod
 call test(a())
end program
```

You can also use constructors in other situations, in compound expressions, or just on the right hand side of simple assignments

```
type :: t
  real :: x
end type

type(t) :: o

o = t(1.0)
```

Example of a user-defined constructor:

```
    type :: t
      real :: x
    end type

    interface t
      module procedure my_init
    end interface

  contains

    function my_init(...) result(res)
      type(t) :: res
      ...
    end function
```

Comment: Genius. I don't know why I haven't thought to do that. Should be simple to implement, thank you!

Comment: Crap, wait, the constructor can't have the same name as the derived type. I guess I could use a different name, but I'd rather use the same name..

Comment: It HAS the same name.

Comment: Yep! I forgot to add the interface